# search python dictionary not showing

Tags: python

I'm new to python and have looked at other couple of questions but couldn't get mine to work. Simply I have a list of elements with their details and what I am trying to do is have an input where the user types the symbol then return the associated detail with the symbol. can someone help me out? when I run the program I see nothing.

```
def eDict():
    elements = {'H':[('N', 'Hydrogen'),('AN', 1), ('M', 1.08)], 
    'He':[('N' 'Helium'), ('AN', 2), ('M', 4.00)], 'Li':[('N' 'Lithium'),
     ('AN', 3), ('M', 6.94)]}

    search(elements, 'H')

def search(values, searchFor):
    for k in values:
        for v in values[k]:
            if searchFor in v:
                return k
    return None

eDict()
```

Comment: Simply print the result of `search(elements, 'H')` or return it back and print `eDict()`?

Comment: @thefourtheye okay I did that and it printed 'He' but not H's details.

Comment: `return k, v` instead of `return k`

Comment: @BryanMoyles that outputed `('He', 'NHelium')`

Comment: It prints `NHelium` because there's a comma missing in your dict and Python is joining the strings together. The comma's also missing for the name of Lithium.

Comment: The structure you are using for each element is ok, but IMHO, it'd be better to make each element a simple tuple, eg `('Hydrogen', 1, 1.08)`. Or if you really need the fields to be named you could use a dict, eg `{'name': 'Hydrogen', 'number': 1, 'mass': 1.08}.

Comment: I see that tzot has shown you how to do it with each element as a dict. Give me a minute or two & I'll show you how to do it with tuples.

Comment: BTW, your atomic mass for Hydrogen is missing a zero. It should be 1.008. Here's a link to the latest [IUPAC atomic weights](http://chemistry.about.com/od/elementfacts/a/atomicweights.htm) of all the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching like this:

```
def search(values, searchFor):
    for element, details in values.items():
        if element == searchFor:
           print element, details #As @PM 2Ring says, for Python 3x you should print (element, details)
```

prints `H [('N', 'Hydrogen'), ('AN', 1), ('M', 1.08)]` for `search(elements, 'H')`

If you want just details, return just details:

```
def search(values, searchFor):
    for element, details in values.items():
        if element == searchFor:
           print details #As @PM 2Ring says, for Python 3x you should print (details)
```

prints `[('N', 'Hydrogen'), ('AN', 1), ('M', 1.08)]` for `search(elements, 'H')`

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting invalid syntax error, just copied the same thing. The error is on the last, `print element, details`

Comment: maybe indents are wrong? I've updated the code, with removing space left from print. If it's again syntax error, what exactly it is telling about? For me it works OK.

Comment: Looping through all the items in a dict to find a single item is very inefficient.

Comment: @Magna : What version of Python are you using? In Python 2 you do `print "something"` but in Python 3 you have to do `print("something")`, the old form will give a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks. yeah the print format was the prob. Bzw is there anyway to format the output? getting rid of the brackets and parenthesis. Something like `N = Hydrogen, An = 2, M = 1.08`

Comment: you can add some output like `for (key, value) in details:          print (str(key) + " = " + str(value))`

Answer (score 2):

A dictionary maps *keys* (in your example, the key is `'H'`) to *values* (in your example: `[('N', 'Hydrogen'),('AN', 1), ('M', 1.08)]`).

So typically all you have to do is:

```
>>> print elements['H']
[('N', 'Hydrogen'),('AN', 1), ('M', 1.08)]
```

However, you might consider converting the values into proper dicts, like this:

```
elements = {'H': {'N': 'Hydrogen', 'AN': 1, 'M': 1.08}, … }
```

This way, you can print either all info for an element, as above, or a specific datum for an element:

```
>>> print elements['H']
{'AN': 1, 'M': 1.08, 'N': 'Hydrogen'}
>>> print elements['H']['M']
1.08
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Python 2.6 version that uses a tuple for each element.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

'''
Simple database of chemical elements
From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25882694/search-python-dictionary-not-showing#25882947
'''

fields = ('Name', 'Atomic number', 'Mass')
elements = {
    'H':  ('Hydrogen', 1, 1.08), 
    'He': ('Helium', 2, 4.00), 
    'Li': ('Lithium', 3, 6.94),
}

import sys

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        symbols = sys.argv[1:]
    else:
        print "No symbols given!"
        exit(1)

    #for k in elements: print "%2s: %s" % (k, elements[k])

    for symbol in symbols:
        element = elements[symbol]
        print 'Symbol: %2s,' % symbol,
        print ', '.join(['%s: %s' % t for t in zip(fields, element)])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you run it like:
`python Elements.py Li He H`
you get

### Output:

```
Symbol: Li, Name: Lithium, Atomic number: 3, Mass: 6.94
Symbol: He, Name: Helium, Atomic number: 2, Mass: 4.0
Symbol:  H, Name: Hydrogen, Atomic number: 1, Mass: 1.08
```

You can make that look nicer by playing with the print formatting.

---

**EDIT**

FWIW, here's a complete elements dict, using that IUPAC data.

```
elements = {
    'H'  : ('Hydrogen', 1, 1.00798),
    'He' : ('Helium', 2, 4.00260),
    'Li' : ('Lithium', 3, 6.96750),
    'Be' : ('Beryllium', 4, 9.01218),
    'B'  : ('Boron', 5, 10.81350),
    'C'  : ('Carbon', 6, 12.01060),
    'N'  : ('Nitrogen', 7, 14.00685),
    'O'  : ('Oxygen', 8, 15.99940),
    'F'  : ('Fluorine', 9, 18.99840),
    'Ne' : ('Neon', 10, 20.17970),
    'Na' : ('Sodium', 11, 22.98977),
    'Mg' : ('Magnesium', 12, 24.30550),
    'Al' : ('Aluminium', 13, 26.98154),
    'Si' : ('Silicon', 14, 28.08500),
    'P'  : ('Phosphorus', 15, 30.97376),
    'S'  : ('Sulfur', 16, 32.06750),
    'Cl' : ('Chlorine', 17, 35.45150),
    'Ar' : ('Argon', 18, 39.94800),
    'K'  : ('Potassium', 19, 39.09830),
    'Ca' : ('Calcium', 20, 40.07800),
    'Sc' : ('Scandium', 21, 44.95591),
    'Ti' : ('Titanium', 22, 47.86700),
    'V'  : ('Vanadium', 23, 50.94150),
    'Cr' : ('Chromium', 24, 51.99610),
    'Mn' : ('Manganese', 25, 54.93804),
    'Fe' : ('Iron', 26, 55.84500),
    'Co' : ('Cobalt', 27, 58.93319),
    'Ni' : ('Nickel', 28, 58.69340),
    'Cu' : ('Copper', 29, 63.54600),
    'Zn' : ('Zinc', 30, 65.38000),
    'Ga' : ('Gallium', 31, 69.72300),
    'Ge' : ('Germanium', 32, 72.63000),
    'As' : ('Arsenic', 33, 74.92159),
    'Se' : ('Selenium', 34, 78.97100),
    'Br' : ('Bromine', 35, 79.90400),
    'Kr' : ('Krypton', 36, 83.79800),
    'Rb' : ('Rubidium', 37, 85.46780),
    'Sr' : ('Strontium', 38, 87.62000),
    'Y'  : ('Yttrium', 39, 88.90584),
    'Zr' : ('Zirconium', 40, 91.22400),
    'Nb' : ('Niobium', 41, 92.90637),
    'Mo' : ('Molybdenum', 42, 95.95000),
    'Tc' : ('Technetium', 43, 98),
    'Ru' : ('Ruthenium', 44, 101.07000),
    'Rh' : ('Rhodium', 45, 102.90550),
    'Pd' : ('Palladium', 46, 106.42000),
    'Ag' : ('Silver', 47, 107.86820),
    'Cd' : ('Cadmium', 48, 112.41400),
    'In' : ('Indium', 49, 114.81800),
    'Sn' : ('Tin', 50, 118.71000),
    'Sb' : ('Antimony', 51, 121.76000),
    'Te' : ('Tellurium', 52, 127.60000),
    'I'  : ('Iodine', 53, 126.90447),
    'Xe' : ('Xenon', 54, 131.29300),
    'Cs' : ('Cesium', 55, 132.90545),
    'Ba' : ('Barium', 56, 137.32700),
    'La' : ('Lanthanum', 57, 138.90547),
    'Ce' : ('Cerium', 58, 140.11600),
    'Pr' : ('Praseodymium', 59, 140.90766),
    'Nd' : ('Neodymium', 60, 144.24200),
    'Pm' : ('Promethium', 61, 145),
    'Sm' : ('Samarium', 62, 150.36000),
    'Eu' : ('Europium', 63, 151.96400),
    'Gd' : ('Gadolinium', 64, 157.25000),
    'Tb' : ('Terbium', 65, 158.92535),
    'Dy' : ('Dysprosium', 66, 162.50000),
    'Ho' : ('Holmium', 67, 164.93033),
    'Er' : ('Erbium', 68, 167.25900),
    'Tm' : ('Thulium', 69, 168.93422),
    'Yb' : ('Ytterbium', 70, 173.05400),
    'Lu' : ('Lutetium', 71, 174.96680),
    'Hf' : ('Hafnium', 72, 178.49000),
    'Ta' : ('Tantalum', 73, 180.94788),
    'W'  : ('Tungsten', 74, 183.84000),
    'Re' : ('Rhenium', 75, 186.20700),
    'Os' : ('Osmium', 76, 190.23000),
    'Ir' : ('Iridium', 77, 192.21700),
    'Pt' : ('Platinum', 78, 195.08400),
    'Au' : ('Gold', 79, 196.96657),
    'Hg' : ('Mercury', 80, 200.59200),
    'Tl' : ('Thallium', 81, 204.38350),
    'Pb' : ('Lead', 82, 207.20000),
    'Bi' : ('Bismuth', 83, 208.98040),
    'Po' : ('Polonium', 84, 209),
    'At' : ('Astatine', 85, 210),
    'Rn' : ('Radon', 86, 222),
    'Fr' : ('Francium', 87, 223),
    'Ra' : ('Radium', 88, 226),
    'Ac' : ('Actinium', 89, 227),
    'Th' : ('Thorium', 90, 232.03770),
    'Pa' : ('Protactinium', 91, 231.03588),
    'U'  : ('Uranium', 92, 238.02891),
    'Np' : ('Neptunium', 93, 237),
    'Pu' : ('Plutonium', 94, 244),
    'Am' : ('Americium', 95, 243),
    'Cm' : ('Curium', 96, 247),
    'Bk' : ('Berkelium', 97, 247),
    'Cf' : ('Californium', 98, 251),
    'Es' : ('Einsteinium', 99, 252),
    'Fm' : ('Fermium', 100, 257),
    'Md' : ('Mendelevium', 101, 258),
    'No' : ('Nobelium', 102, 259),
    'Lr' : ('Lawrencium', 103, 262),
    'Rf' : ('Rutherfordium', 104, 267),
    'Db' : ('Dubnium', 105, 268),
    'Sg' : ('Seaborgium', 106, 271),
    'Bh' : ('Bohrium', 107, 272),
    'Hs' : ('Hassium', 108, 270),
    'Mt' : ('Meitnerium', 109, 276),
    'Ds' : ('Darmstadtium', 110, 281),
    'Rg' : ('Roentgenium', 111, 280),
    'Cn' : ('Copernicium', 112, 285),
    'Uut': ('Ununtrium', 113, 284),
    'Fl' : ('Flerovium', 114, 289),
    'Uup': ('Ununpentium', 115, 288),
    'Lv' : ('Livermorium', 116, 293),
    'Uuo': ('Ununoctium', 118, 294),
}
```